# Unable to exceute the code inside the catch block, when there is a file exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am unable to execute a code inside catch block when there is a file exception. Below is the code.

```
try {

        // Check for file size. which will make sure file exists in local server.
        filesize($localPath);
        return 'success';
    }catch(FileException $e) {

        Log::error('Error reading file size ' . $e->getMessage());
        $failedAttempts = $failedAttempts + 1;

        // Set to sleep for 10.
        sleep(10);

        // Start recursive call.
        $this->downloadMedia($url, $localPath, $failedAttempts);
    }
```

I also tried \Exception and \ErrorException but nothing worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if You check [this manual](https://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) You'll see `filesize` method does not throw exception.

> Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE
>
> (and generates an error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.

and since looks like You've not enabled error reporting or `display_error` directive - You don't see that **E_WARNING**

You can just throw exception manually:

```
try {

    // Check for file existence or throw exception.
    if (!is_file($localPath)) {
      throw new Exception($localPath.' does not exists');
    }
    return 'success';
}
catch(Exception $e) {

 // here goes exception handling
}
```

**Extra advice (out of question's scope)**:

There is no logic to check for file existence in recurring way.

If file is downloaded it will exist otherwise You'll never download it during recursion.

What if someone will pass link to file that does not exists?

Better jus download it and stop with success or exception.

Comment: if there is no file, there is no point in trying to download it further, in the next round

Comment: @Takamura it's the same function, Juluri tries to check for file existence again "fancy way" using recursion (: about my answer - his question is about why function does not throw error in `try..catch`. so I've explained why. but in fact that way of doing download is incorrect. So I agree with You.

Comment: num8er if the file is missing for a long time, a memory overflow may occur, is it better to use an iterator? )

Comment: @Takamura man, I'm answering by context of question. I don't care if someone wrote overflowing code

Comment: @Takamura btw php will not have memory overflow for that block of code since it's just iterating integer variable. It will stop execute in terms of `recursion_limit` in config of PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php and for 1000 recursion limit and 10 seconds sleep it will take ~6 days which someone (admins, hosting providers) will get informed that something goes wrong.